Spark mask function can't handle correctly for string if contains invalid UTF-8 character or wide character
In the spark the mask function when apply with a stirng contains invalid character or wide character would cause unexpected behavior.
Example to use * mask a stirng contains wide-character 
select mask("", "Y", "y", "n", "*");

could cause result ** instead of *.
Example to use wide-character  do mask would cause wrong garbled code problem
select mask("ABC", "");

result is ???.
Example to mask a string contains a invalid UTF-8 character
 select mask("\xED");

result is xXX instead of \xED, looks spark treat it as four character \, x, E, D.
Looks spark mask can only handle BMP character (that is 16 bits) and can't guarantee result for invalid UTC-8 character and wide-character when doing mask.
Does that the limitation / issue of spark mask function or spark mask by design only handle for BMP character ?

anyone can help ?
